# Merge/Migrate two or more categories and rename it to one in Magento

Tags: magento, product, categories, catalog

I have a magento website that has couple of thousands of products. Now Suppose I have a category X with sub categories S1, S2, S3 having 1000 products. Same way I have another category Y with SAME sub categories S1, S2, S3 having another set of 1000 products.
Now I have to combine both the products (along with the SAME sub categories) into another category Z.

How is it possible?

Comment: Magento default don't have this functionality but we can achieve this by custom script. In your custom script assign Z category ID(Sub category) to all products respectively.

Comment: you able to fix this?

Comment: if not then you have to create the category Z and just insert all the 1000 products_id and category_id of Z into catalog_category_product